# I have already made a weekly schedule with the help of the below code but help needed how to reschedule

Tags: php

```
<?php

$start = new DateTime( '2019-01-04' );
$end =58;
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $dayOfWeek = $date->format('l');
    if ($dayOfWeek == 'Saturday' || $dayOfWeek == 'Monday' || $dayOfWeek == 'Wednesday') {
        print $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '   ' . $dayOfWeek ;
    }

}
```

I want to make a Weekly schedule on the basis of week days.Is it the right way to do with the above code or any other solutions...

Output result will be the total number of class on the basis of selective weekdays like saturday,monday,wednesday and suppose number of class will be 25

If possible let me know how to reschedule those days if there is any change on this schedule..

Thanks...

Comment: do you want to count total number of classes for selected days.

Comment: Exactly..But Once i have assigned total class to selected date to database. is there any way to reschedule it..

Comment: can you update question with example of reschedule?

Answer (score 0):

For Total classes, you can use below code.

```
<?php

$start = new DateTime( '2019-01-04' );
$end =58;
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
$cntclass = 0;
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $dayOfWeek = $date->format('l');
    if ($dayOfWeek == 'Saturday' || $dayOfWeek == 'Monday' || $dayOfWeek == 'Wednesday') {
        print $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '   ' . $dayOfWeek ;
        echo '<br>';
          $cntclass++;
    }

}

Echo '<br>';
Echo 'Total classes  ', $cntclass;

?>
```